# What does this function symbol on my Cylinda convection oven mean?

Tags: oven, convection

On the right hand knob, there are eight options including `0` (off):

[image: Oven function symbols]

> #2 has always been puzzling me and I've assumed the rest mean something like the list below. Please tell me if I'm wrong about these
> too as I remember hearing some ovens have a "back element" for use
> with the fan.
>
> 1. Light only
> 2. <s>Fan with ???</s>
> 3. Fan with only the exposed grill/broil element. <s>*(AKA "Pizza mode")*</s>
> 4. <s>Fan with only the bottom element.</s>
> 5. Fan with <s>top and bottom elements **without** the exposed grill/broil element? (I'm not actually sure about this one. I guess
>    this could mean something like</s> "back element **only**"<s>, if
>    there is a back element in this)</s>
> 6. Only the exposed grill/broil element.
> 7. Top and bottom elements <s>**without** the exposed grill/broil element.</s>
>
> <s>My best guess for #2 has been that it's similar to the the `S`
> (super?) function on some ovens (all heating elements including the
> broiler at the same time, for rapid preheating of the oven itself) but
> I'm not sure as I don't know where the oven's user manual is and can't
> find a model name or number in order to find it online. (No Cylinda
> oven manual I've found online feature symbol #2 or anything similar to
> it)</s>
>
> <s>In my experience,</s> option #5 heats the oven up faster than #7 <s>so I
> have used #5 for preheating, but I haven't actually tested whether
> this is actually true or not.   It would be nice to know whether #2 is
> ***the function specifically for this use***.</s>

EDIT: I found the model number, it's `A46010003`. This only led me to a spare parts website, but that site had the name *`CYLINDA IB 30`* beside the number. With this name, I was able to find a [*Swedish-only* user manual (pdf)](https://www.gransbygden.se/static/files/bruksanvisning-cylinda-ib30.pdf) with the exact symbols.
The functions according to that manual (and some quick maths) get us to:

| Symbol | Name | kW | Top | Grill | Bottom | Fan | Back |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| #7 | över/undervärme | 2.1 | [series- | -series] | ON |  |  |
| #6 | grill | 2.1 |  | ON |  |  |  |
| #5 | varmluft | 2.35 |  |  |  | ON | ON |
| #4 | pizza | 3.35 |  |  | ON | ON | ON |
| #3 | varmluftsgrill | 2.1 |  | ON |  | ON |  |
| #2 | upptining/torkning | 0.515 | [series- | -series- | -series] | ON |  |

With limited Swedish proficiency I gathered that #2 is for drying stuff with the door left slightly ajar, and that #5 is **True Convection** in its *strictest sense*, using just the back heating element.

Comment: Well done for answering your own question. The only other answer seems to be quite wrong.

Answer (score 2):

### TL;DR

The other symbols are fairly industry-standard, even though specific names will change based on where you live & who manufactured the oven.

I believe symbol #2 is similar to #4, with the distinction that #2 is designed to be used when cooking multiple things on multiple racks of the oven, where #4 is designed to bake a single item in the center of your oven.

### Longer version

I thought this was interesting, so I did some flipping through some manuals I found online (mostly [this Cylinda](https://resurs.cylinda.se/bilder/59344/IBU%2096_1.pdf) and [this miele](https://www.mieleusa.com/pmedia/ZGA/TX2070/9898041-000-02_9898041-02.pdf)). I still didn't see anything that looks exactly like #2 in your question, but I have some guesses.

I think those seven settings equate to:

1. Oven Light
2. Forced Air
3. Convection/Fan Broil/Grill
4. "Intensive"
5. Convection/Fan Bake
6. Broil/Grill
7. Conventional Oven

Some of these are brand-specific mode names, so digging a little deeper into the manuals:

- Difference between "Forced Air" vs "Convection Bake" ([Cylinda manual, Page 38](https://resurs.cylinda.se/bilder/59344/IBU%2096_1.pdf))

  - Forced Air - For cooking different foods that require the same cooking temperature on several shelves (maximum three) at the same time. This function can be used to cook different foods without odours being transferred from one food to another.
  - Convection Bake - For cooking meat or baking cakes with liquid centre on a single shelf.
- Intensive Mode - This mode gently circulates heated air from the lower heating element using the fan to create a brick oven environment. Ideal for baking pizza, focaccia, pies and tarts that require a crisp base and moist toppings. ([miele manual, Page 56](https://www.mieleusa.com/pmedia/ZGA/TX2070/9898041-000-02_9898041-02.pdf))

Comment: Was about to answer the same as you.

Comment: This leads me to believe it has three heating elements in total: Bottom, top (same physical element as the broiler, but when broiling it gets much hotter) and back (around the fan, can only be used with the fan running). In terms of what heating elements might be active #2 probably only uses the back element to avoid making the bottom and the top hotter than the middle ("True Convection"), while #5 uses them all ("Convection Bake") and #4 probably only uses the bottom while running the fan cold. ...and it makes sense that #5 would preheat the oven the fastest!

Comment: Or is #2 the ONLY mode that has the back element on at all? I'm finding conflicting information on what these modes are. Some manufacturers say that "True Convection" is **only** the back element, and others say it's **all three**, and vice versa some manufacturers say that "Convection Bake" is just "Bake" (top and bottom) with a the fan added ("American" or "Traditional" convection) and others say **and the back element**. Come to think of the symbols #2 and #5, they are just ambiguous on which means which; the squiggles on the sides could be either "more heat" or vertical interchangeability.

Comment: I don't think this indicates a third heating element. I believe it's just a matter of how the two elements and fan are used. My guess (without knowing your specific oven model) is that it would use more, shorter cycles of the heating elements, and more consistent or stronger fan cycles.

Comment: The symbol in #5 **is** a standard symbol to mean "convection oven" or "bake with fan". The added `S` symbols are non standard, hence deciding that they belong to the non-standard oven mode.